# Cross-browser incompatibility, how to put the button "同意して、アカウントを作成します" back into the big box?

Tags: html, firefox, layout, cross-browser, incompatibility

If you visit http://www.tenxian.com/jp/common/signup.php? with Firefox, you will find that the button "同意して、アカウントを作成します" is out of the box; if you access this web page with IE, then there is no problem. How to fix this problem(put "同意して、アカウントを作成します" back into the box in Firefox)?

Comment: On Firefox 3.6, it display fine but on IE8 I don't see any japanese text, it's just square blocks.

Comment: What? I adopt "charset=utf-8", how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `height` on the `.signup` in your CSS.